# Computer compatible keyboard for synthesizer? Where to start?

Tags: piano, digital-piano, synthesizer

I'm slightly familiar with stackexchange culture...so take note I am not asking for a product suggestion. 
My son is getting into music and I wanted to get him a keyboard that can be interfaced with a computer for post-editing. I know little in music.

Doing some initial research, I see most instruments are those I knew in the 90's. Or at least, very similar. Hence, I find I am probably very error prone in this modern situation.

What type of electronic keyboard / piano is needed to get:
A: a basic knowledge of the piano / keyboard to learn music.
B: can interface with a computer allowing post editing.

...so for instance, electronic drums could be recorded on instrument into computer, then guitar stuff, etc.

For now I've sent away for a cheap Midi keyboard to hold over until I get a quality instrument for him, but I know this is nothing like the real thing. More just to get his interest started.

This choice, I feel, allows him to produce a large variety of creations on one instrument and workflow (ie, without purchasing tons of instruments) while learning one of the more important instruments in music.

Comment: What kind of post-editing are you interested in doing? I think most electronic pianos can be connected to a computer to record directly. Regarding point A, any keyboard is fine to learn music. If the interest is to approach acoustic piano and learning classical music, look for keyboards with weighted keys and at least 4 octaves range

Comment: "For now I've sent away for a cheap Midi keyboard" - a MIDI keyboard will be possible to connect to a computer and create things that can be edited, so it seems like you've already found an answer to "Where to start?"...

Comment: MIDI might be what you want because with a fitting DAW software and VST plugins can be the base for endless creations. But you won't capture the true sound of the keyboard, as MIDI is only an abstract digital protocol. To capture the sound the keyboard should have a dedicated output. You need an audio interface for both options. You better ask recording questions at https://sound.stackexchange.com/ while part A of your question does indeed fits here, I think.

Comment: @Matt To add to what you say, the OP should probably appreciate that it's now very common to use a MIDI keyboard for the purposes of controlling a 'virtual' synth within the computer - and there's not necessarily anything second-rate about those sounds as compared to the sounds in the keyboard itself. This is something that wasn't true throughout most of the 90s!

Comment: Thank you everyone. This is very helpful. I like music but know nothing about it. Wanted to get my son started in the right direction.